# How to assign unique numbers to the tree nodes so that from the tree leaf I can trace back the parents?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have to structure certain data and tree data structure suited the requirement.
I have to assign certain number to each node in such a manner that I can trace back the parent from its number. I am planning to use hashtable to store these numbers as keys, so there cannot be any duplicate value.

e.g.

parent - 000001
  child1  - 000011
    innerchild1 - 000111   (level 2, get 2 bits from right and we can reach parent)
    innerchild2 - 000211
  child2  - 000021
    innerchild1 - 000121
    innerchild2 - 000221

Depending on the level, I can mask certain bits and I can uniquely identify the parent.
But if my tree grows wider(i.e. more parents, numbers will duplicate)
How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why does the trace back have to be numeric? Some reason why a normal tree structure (getParent, getChildren, ...) would not satisfy the requirement.

Comment: why do you need to "trace back the parent". what's the actual need?

Comment: I need to construct a string from the children and parent, I don't want to cache the string when I traverse down, rather would like to create a whole string from the leaf traversing back.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to use numbers with digits 1-9.

Why no-0?
9-digit number with leading 0 looks as 8-digit on without leading 0. It will cause errors.

Thus, till any parent has maximally 9 children, the structure will suffice.

number 0 - common root
1-9 - first children
11-19 - second generation children of the first child...
and so on

If you'll have nodes with more than 9 digits, use 100-base arithmetic. (allowed digits will be 10-99). Are 99 children enough? If not, use 100-999.

Comment: -1 using number/string to define parent-child relationship would not be a good solution. only if there is special requirements. And OP do mentioned, "if the tree goes wider" and "more parents", what if currently 99 children are enough for a certain level, but it turns out in 6 months, the parent node could have 9999 children?

Comment: 1. *mostly* it is a bad way. But I am far from declaring it bad for all times. And the questioner asked for this very way. 2. More *children*, not "more parents". A node in a tree can't have more than one parent. Being critique, try to be at least adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Nested set tree can be used yo solve the problem. Please refer to the book below. Its an amazing book, which also contain text on Nested Set trees.

http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/bookdescription.cws_home/702605/description

Comment: Your answer relates to storing a tree in an SQL database. How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: I was trying to pinpoint the technique used to query nodes for their meta information ( example their parents ). It can be build in such a fashion. The questioner can get some idea from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of assigning "special" numbers to nodes sounds like a bad one - likely to lead to a lot of hard work, scalability limitations and most of all... bugs.

If you need to know what the parent node is, store a reference to the parent node in a field of the node!

Comment: yeah, even I had that in mind(i.e it may lead to bugs and more work). Thought of trying to use hashtable with unique numbers as key for quick access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a "well defined" number as key is good enough.

You need design a tree structure for your requirement or at least a Node class to get parentId/parent Node easier.

for example

```
Node{
 id, #could be string, number, unique
 actualNode # you node value
 parentId (or Node parentNode )
}
```

if you would stick to hashtable for some reason, you can still use the node.id as key. there are a number of ways to generate unique string, numbers. e.g. current nano-seconds ...

Comment: Thought hash-table with numbers can improve the performance of access, but finally I think I will have to go with your approach.